# `\definecolor` within `\foreach` loop

Tags: color, expansion, foreach

I am trying to make this loop work:

```
\foreach \name/\col in {first/{204, 0, 0},%
                       second/{0, 102, 0},%
                        third/{0, 0, 153}}{%
    \definecolor{\name}{RGB}{\col} % buggish line
    \expandafter\xdef\csname\name\endcsname##1{\noexpand\textcolor{\name}{##1}}
    % + more convenience utilities..
}
```

.. but the colors seems not to be defined, since I get

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `first'.
```

When I try to use them. I have try to fiddle-faddle with many combinations of `\expandafter`, `\noexpand`, `\relax` *etc.* with no success and no real strategy. What is the reasoning to get them right?

In the end, I expect:

```
here is a \first{custom}-\second{colored} \third{text}
```

to produce:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the same reason you need `\xdef`, you need `\xglobal\definecolor` (section 2.5.5 in the manual of `xcolor`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pgffor}

\foreach \name/\col in {%
  first/{204, 0, 0},%
  second/{0, 102, 0},%
  third/{0, 0, 153}%
}{%
  \xglobal\definecolor{\name}{RGB}{\col} % buggish line
  \expandafter\xdef\csname\name\endcsname##1{\noexpand\textcolor{\name}{##1}}
  % + more convenience utilities..
}

\begin{document}

here is a \first{custom}-\second{colored} \third{text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd be wary about using such an approach, because you risk to overwrite commands, with possibly disastrous effects.

Here's code that's free of that problem (colors are silently overridden, though):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definebunchofcolors}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \iagolito_define_color:n { ##1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \iagolito_define_color:n
 {
  \__iagolito_define_color_aux:nn #1
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__iagolito_define_color_aux:nn
 {
  \definecolor{#1}{RGB}{#2}
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } ##1 { \textcolor{#1}{##1} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definebunchofcolors{
  {first}{204, 0, 0},
  {second}{0, 102, 0},
  {third}{0, 0, 153}
}

\begin{document}

here is a \first{custom}-\second{colored} \third{text}

\end{document}
```

However, you don't gain much with this approach: it's simpler to do one declaration at a time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setupcolor}{mO{RGB}m}
 {
  \definecolor{#1}{#2}{#3}
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } ##1 { \textcolor{#1}{##1} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setupcolor{first}{204, 0, 0}
\setupcolor{second}{0, 102, 0}
\setupcolor{third}[rgb]{0, 0, 0.6}

\begin{document}

here is a \first{custom}-\second{colored} \third{text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Neat, clear and perfect. Cheers :)

Answer (score 9):

Definitions in a `\foreach` loop are local (unless made global), so the definitions of the colors with `\definecolor` are unknown outside, in particular when you try to access them with your `\textcolor` command.

Why do you use a loop? I see no advantage of `\foreach \x in {a,b,c} {\dosomething{\x}}` over `\dosomething{a}\dosomething{b}\dosomething{c}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\newcolor[2]%
  {\definecolor{#1}{RGB}{#2}%
   \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1]{\textcolor{#1}{##1}}%
   % + more convenience utilities..
  }
\newcolor{first}{204, 0, 0}
\newcolor{second}{0, 102, 0}
\newcolor{third}{0, 0, 153}
\begin{document}
here is a \first{custom}-\second{colored} \third{text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yaï! This is much, much neater indeed. Cheers for that :)

Comment: One (very **very** slight) downside: I need to define a new command and pick up a name for it, whereas I do not need that with a `\foreach` loop. However, I like the way it is much more easy to deal with `\csname` *etc.* with your strategy. I will accept egreg's answer because it is closer from OP, but I'll still use your solution in this case :) Thanks again!